# Drain Plug Crush Washer- Installed wrong size

Tags: oil, nissan, drain, frontier, plug

Nissan Frontier 2018 4.0L. SV
Parts store said I could use any washer in an assorted pack of washers labeled M14. Upon looking further into issue I found that a M12 is the correct size. I already installed the M14. It is not leaking now. Will that be OK until next oil change? Or change it now.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 5):

My "opinion" is, you should change it now. If it's too big, even if sealed now, will want to allow the bolt to loosen up at some point. Whether it gets loose enough for the bolt to fall out or just loose enough for it to start leaking, neither thing is good. If it were me, I'd get it changed.

Comment: Is there any way to change the washer without oil gushing out? I imagine attaching a vacuum cleaner to the oil fill hole would reduce the outflow, but be messy in a different way.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - Well, having quick fingers helps. You'll need to put something under it because you WILL lose some oil in the process. If you're quick about it, you should be able to get it done fairly easy and not lose much oil. Use an off hand finger to quickly plug the hole immediately after removing the plug, you should be in pretty good shape. You'll want to do this when the engine is cold ... hot oil burns ... literally, lol. :o)

Comment: Consider having a second set of hands to help you ... changing out a washer all by your lonesome while playing the part of the Little Dutch Boy is not all that easy. It can be done, but not a lot of fun ;-)